# How to choose images from gallery or camera in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, image-uploading, image-gallery, android-camera-intent

I have a Fragment from where I am uploading images from gallery or taking photo from camera but while running the app "App has stopped" message is coming in Android emulator and app is not opening. This is my **FragmentEncode** class. Is this not the right way to Upload image from Gallery or Camera in Fragments? If not then what's the right way?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;

import com.stegano.strenggeheim.R;


public class FragmentEncode extends Fragment {
    private ImageView imageview;
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/encoded_image";
    private static final int GALLERY = 1, CAMERA = 2;
    Uri myPicture = null;
    Button buttonLoadImage;
    Context context = getContext();

    public FragmentEncode() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        buttonLoadImage = buttonLoadImage.findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadImage);
        imageview =  imageview.findViewById(R.id.imageToEncode);

        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPictureDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showPictureDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action");
        String[] pictureDialogItems = {
                "Select photo from gallery",
                "Capture photo from camera" };
        pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                choosePhotoFromGallary();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                takePhotoFromCamera();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
        pictureDialog.show();
    }

    public void choosePhotoFromGallary() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);
    }

    private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_encode, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri contentURI = data.getData();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                    String path = saveImage(bitmap);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            saveImage(thumbnail);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        File wallpaperDirectory = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
        // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        try {
            File f = new File(wallpaperDirectory, Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
                    new String[]{f.getPath()},
                    new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
            fo.close();

            return f.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Do you have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE into the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes I already did.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_encode, container, false);

    buttonLoadImage = buttonLoadImage.findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadImage);
    imageview =  imageview.findViewById(R.id.imageToEncode);

    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showPictureDialog();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

and below

```
Context context = getContext();
```

put

```
View view;
```

Comment: Your answer will most likely be more helpful if you explain your changes a little bit.